# How to wait for an async call from an eventhandler

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I have the following event handler:

```
  Private Async Sub DatabaseRestored(sender As RestoreBackupViewModel)
        _success = Await _applicationManager.ReinitializeAsync
    End Sub
```

The problem is that I really need to know if the `ReinitializeAsync` function has completed before initiating other actions.
When I change the code to:

```
  Private Sub DatabaseRestored(sender As RestoreBackupViewModel)
        _success = _applicationManager.ReinitializeAsync.Result
    End Sub
```

The code deadlocks.

How to handle this?

Comment: Well, call another method that starts whatever needs to be stated one line after `Await _applicationManager.ReinitializeAsync()`. Or, do you mean that you have UI elements that need to be disabled before that method returns, so an User cannot start something that cannot be started until you get whatever that method is returning?

Comment: Does it deadlock if you call the method without `Await` and get the `Task` it returns, then call `Wait` on that and then get the `Result`? If so then you simply have badly written code and you need to fix it.

Comment: Does setting [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) (for this project, and it's best to set it as the default for new projects too) show any problems? Event handlers usually have `(sender As Object, e as EventArgs)` (or derived types) as their parameters; the code in the question is missing the EventArgs parameter.

Comment: @AndrewMorton A deadlock in this situation is unsurprising and has nothing to do with event arguments (though I agree with your advice in general).

Comment: @jmcilhinney The fundamental problem is blocking on the task in the UI thread.  "Badly written" underlying code is debatable, the general advice is "don't do that".  You can try to ensure that `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used at every level, but if you miss one, you're toast.  Also see Stephen Cleary here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 2):

I solved it thus:

```
   Private Async Function DatabaseRestoredAsync() As Task
        _success = Await _applicationManager.ReinitializeAsync
    End Function
```

So, no event and eventhandler any more. Simply a call back (`Func(Of Task)`) that is passed to the class that otherwise would subscribe to the event an can now await it. Possible memory leaks seem not a concern at this point.

The class that otherwise would subscribe to the event now has code like:

```
Await _databaseRestoredCallback.Invoke()
```

instead of

```
RaiseEvent DatabaseRestored(Me)
```

The `_databaseRestoredCallback` field referencing the `DatabaseRestoredAsync` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
_success = _applicationManager.ReinitializeAsync.GetAwaiter().Result
```